# Two ways to define differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset.
Then there are two ways to define a differential form:

- algebraically as in
  [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398275/definition-of-differential-forms-from-derivations),
  were one considers the real algebra $A$ of smooth functions $A$,
  the module of real derivations and then its exterior algebra;
- geometrically, as smooth maps
  $$\omega \colon U \to \operatorname{Alt}^p(\mathbb{R}^n).$$

This second approach is used in most differential geometry books,
such as Henri Cartan's Differential forms.
One possible advantage in the second approach is that one can
consider $C^k$ maps
$$\omega \colon U \subseteq E \to \operatorname{Alt}^p(E, F)$$
where $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces. The apparent disadvantage is that
one has to do a lot of work to give an algebraic structure to those maps.

I have never seen a discussion on the relation between those two
definitions so here are some natural questions:

1. Is it trivial to go from algebraic to geometric definition and back
   (in the particular case of $E = \mathbb{R}^n$, $F = \mathbb{R}$)?
2. Is there an equivalence / adjunction?
3. Has this something to do with the relation between bundles and
   lf. modules of sheaves (the algebro-geometric duality)?

---

If i understand correctly, the relation should be
$$
\Lambda^p(\mathcal{D}^1(C^{\infty}(U, F))) =
C^{\infty}(U, \operatorname{Alt}^p(E, F))
$$
where one shows that the second gadget has a well defined wedge product.
The first gadget represents the alternating functor, hence
$$
\operatorname{Alt}^p(\mathcal{D}^1(C^{\infty}(U, F)), N) =
\operatorname{Hom}(C^{\infty}(U, \operatorname{Alt}^p(E, F)), N)
$$
for any $A$-module $N$ where $A = C^{\infty}(U, F)$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by question 2.

Comment: @EricWofsey Neither do i. I just tought that, since we are moving around arrows in a canonical way, maybe there was some categorical relation in place. I'm fine with any explanation tbh.